# How can i get an image form web service?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiimage

How to download an image to show it in an `UITableView` from web services and being able to download it again when I scroll `UITableView`?

Any guide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should place image download
       section in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`
       method
2. You'd better provide a
       link to image via service if that is
       possible.

Comment: when i scroll table than it will also download again and its a time consuming process

Comment: You have to add a manual check whether image is already downloaded or not. It'll be good to keep downloaded images in an array of images, if there are not too much rows. In case there are much rows I'll believe it's time to think about pagination.